# Laravel automatic redirect url from http to https

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I want to redirect from http to https automatically for my Laravel app.

url is app1.domain.com

I've added the following lines to the .htaccess file in my public folder, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

When I type `http://app1.domain.com`, the url is not redirected and stays on `http`. When I click to access my app via `http://app1.domain.com/auth/login`, I get a 404. If I manually add the `https` to `https://app1.domain.com/auth/login`, then it works, but I'd like it if could redirect to `https` automatically.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Added those 2 lines for ssl redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Also tried changing my laravel .env file from `APP_URL=http://app1.domain.com` to `APP_URL=https://app1.domain.com`, but didn't do anything.

**SOLUTION**

Use web server to redirect all http requests to https.

So changed my `httpd.conf` file from:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.app1.domain.com
    ServerAlias app1.domain.com
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1.domain.com/public
</VirtualHost>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.app1.domain.com
    ServerAlias app1.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://app1.domain.com/  <-- this line added
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1.domain.com/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to `service httpd restart`

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Where is it hosted, it's not using nginx is it?

Comment: Hosted on a vps, using Apache

Comment: Ok, you've `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: Have you checked to see if other htaccess redirects work. Like a 301 or anything like that to see if theres any other underlying issues?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess file already existed, I just added the two lines above. I"ll post it

Comment: Well, my 2 lines above are basic, do you have an example of what I can try?

Comment: Move the cond and rule up before `# Handle Front Controller...`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work neither

Comment: I found a solution that seem to work ok (using web server to redirect all http requests to https). See solution above. thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

I use a middleware function, and just apply it to all routes. Then you can take it off if you need to for any particular url

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri(), 301);
        }

        return $next($request); 
   }
}
```

then add to your kernel.php file

```
    'https' => [
        'App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol'   
    ],
```

then just tack this on to your route like this

```
 Route::get('/', ['middleware' => array('web','https'),'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

or register it globally

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware)

Comment: Shouldn't it be a better practice to do this outside of Laravel? Did you do this because it wasn't working for you using .htaccess file?

Comment: I did actually have trouble getting htaccess to work reliably in all cases without writing a bunch of conditions. You may argue the htaccess is cleaner, but they are both redirecting the request, and doing it inside laravel allows you to extend it later if you need to. Im sure there is an argument for either way of doing it. But this works and its easier and more extendable.

Comment: Thanks for your input @severian, I really appreciate. I found a solution that seem to work ok (using web server to redirect all http requests to https). See solution above

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It worked for me.